# Calculations always equal 0

Tags: android, int, double, calculator

I have this chunk of code, whenever I enter any value the result always comes up as 0. I set breakpoints inside each if statement and the values being used in the calculation are always valid, but liming is still 
It may also be worth noting that `soilDepth` and `rnv` are integers. I tried casting them to doubles, just in case, and nothing changed.

```
final TextView limingTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.limingText);

double liming;

if (targetPh == 6.8) {
    liming = (71.4 - 1.03 * bufferpH * 10) * (soilDepth / 8) * (65 / rnv);
} else if (targetPh == 6.5) {
    liming = (60.4 - .87 * bufferpH * 10) * (soilDepth / 8) * (65 / rnv);
} else if (targetPh == 6.0) {
    liming = (49.3 - .71 * bufferpH * 10) * (soilDepth / 8) * (65 / rnv);
} else { //If 6.8 is left as default on drop down menu its not passed
    liming = (71.4 - 1.03 * bufferpH * 10) * (soilDepth / 8) * (65 / rnv);
}

limingTV.setText(String.format("%.4f lbs/acre", liming));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Bhush_Techidiot says, cast to double before the math starts. Div with ints doesn't work like you expect it to.

```
  final TextView limingTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.limingText);

  double liming;
  double dblSoilDepth = (double) soilDepth;
  double dblRnv = (double) rnv;

  if (targetPh == 6.8) {
      liming = (71.4 - 1.03 * bufferpH * 10) * (dblSoilDepth / 8) * (65 / dblRnv);
  } else if (targetPh == 6.5) {
      liming = (60.4 - .87 * bufferpH * 10) * (dblSoilDepth / 8) * (65 / dblRnv);
  } else if (targetPh == 6.0) {
    liming = (49.3 - .71 * bufferpH * 10) * (dblSoilDepth / 8) * (65 / dblRnv);
  } else { //If 6.8 is left as default on drop down menu its not passed
    liming = (71.4 - 1.03 * bufferpH * 10) * (dblSoilDepth / 8) * (65 / dblRnv);
  }

  limingTV.setText(String.format("%.4f lbs/acre", liming));
```

Comment: Like I stated at the end of my post, I did try that, but liming is still 0.
 'code'else { //If 6.8 is left as default on drop down menu its not passed
      liming = (71.4 - 1.03 * bufferpH * 10.0) * (double)(soilDepth / 8) * (double)(65 / rnv);
      Log.v("liming is", String.valueOf(liming));
     } // Liming is : 0.0

Comment: @CodyHarness : `(double)(soilDepth / 8)` won't work as you're casting the result of `(soilDepth / 8)` to a `double` and *NOT* `soilDepth`. In other words you're still performing an integer division  (causing a result of 0) then casting *THAT* to a `double` giving 0.0

Comment: @Squonk ah, that did it. I'm still not sure that I understand why it would cause a problem though, if I were to enter something like 16 for soil depth.

Comment: As @Squonk said, parenthesis and order of operations are important.

Comment: @CodyHarness Assume that `intNumber = 10;`. When you divide a number by integer the result will be integer. Now when you write `(double)(9/intNumber)`, the second parenthesis's result is an int which is 0 in this case and casting it to double makes no difference. But in `(9/ (double) intNumber)`, first the intNumber casts to double and then the division happens. So the result will be in double (0.9) and not 0 actually.

Comment: @NavidEivazzadeh Thank you for the explanation. I definitely thought it would see the cast and perform the operation inside of it, then cast the result to a double.

Comment: @NavidEivazzadeh I added your idea into my answer

Comment: @CodyHarness : **"I'm still not sure that I understand why it would cause a problem though, if I were to enter something like 16 for soil depth"** : But when you tried a soil depth of 16 are you sure `rnv` wasn't a value  which might cause `(65 / rnv)` to *ALSO* result in an integer division which was also rounded to 0?

Comment: @CoryRoy That's great :)

Answer (score 3):

Integer divisions can cause 0 values.

Try something like -

```
double result = ((double)x) / y;
```

You need to convert one or both soilDepth and rnv as doubles.

To add more, you can also try this (without casting)

```
double result = x * 1.0/y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `int`s to `double` before calculating the results.

```
double newSoilDepth = (double) soilDepth;
double newRnv = (double) rnv;
```

Then use the new doubles in calculations. This can be led to a cleaner code.